# Re-looping an array item in a for loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I have a for loop that checks for conditions and I want to know if I can re-run an item through the loop if it doesn't meet the condition after I make some changes to variables.
is it possible to add something to my else statement that will allow me to re-run the same $item under new conditions?

```
$array_1 = array();
$arraynumber = 0;
foreach($test_array as $item) {
     if($item[2] == $test_array[$y][2]) {
          $array_1[$arraynumber][] = $item;
          $z++;
     } else {
          $arraynumber++;
          $y = $y+$z;
          $z=0;

          echo $item[2];
     }
}
```

The solution turns out to be this, just for those interested:

```
foreach($test_array as $item) {
if($item[2] == $test_array[$y][2]) {
  $array_1[$arraynumber][] = $item;
 $z++;
}elseif($item[2] == $test_array[$y+$z][2]){
$array_1[$arraynumber+1][] = $item;

 $y = $y+$z;
  $z=1;

  $arraynumber++;
}else{
$array_1[$arraynumber+2][] = $item;
 $z++;
 $y = $y+$z;
  $z=0;
  $arraynumber++;

echo $item[2];
}
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest you explain what you're *actually* trying to do, the algorithm or problem you're trying to solve. Not "rerunning an element", the larger picture.

Comment: `prev($test_array)` might work

Comment: goto php function will help.

Comment: @deceze I've made posts before about the whole issue but it seems to either get very few responses and generally not usable ones. The problem is I want to run a function that sorts the content of my array into a multidimensional array clustering the results. I want to use it for sorting by date for instance, so I can show everything from a certain day, week and month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> re-run **an** item through the loop

You could use [**`prev()`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.prev.php) which will set the internal data pointer 1 step back.

```
prev($test_array); //will re-run the current element in the next iteration
```

Comment: Thanks, it didn't turn out to be the solution but it is the answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
While(true){
//your code
}
```

before the for loop, but make sure you break the loop, otherwise it will become infinite loop and hanged your server.

Answer (score 1):

```
$array_1 = array();
$arraynumber = 0;
foreach($test_array as $item) {
  if($item[2] == $test_array[$y][2]) {
     $array_1[$arraynumber][] = $item;
     $z++;
  }elseif("Your Second statment"){
   echo 'Your second Task';
  }else{
    $arraynumber++;
    $y = $y+$z;
    $z=0;

    echo $item[2];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use <kbd>[GOTO](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php)</kbd> .

**Example**

```
<?php
for($i=0,$j=50; $i<100; $i++) {
  while($j--) {
    if($j==17) goto end; 
  }  
}
echo "i = $i";
end:
echo 'j hit 17';
?>
```

Comment: `goto` is not a function, and bad practice.

Comment: you may use [break 2](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) instead of goto

Comment: @Voitcus in the example, that would create different results.

Comment: @BartFriederichs yes, I edited it to `break 2`

Comment: @BartFriederichs can you tell me why its bad practice...cause i don't know it so need to clear myself

Comment: @DipeshParmar check this out http://www.php.net/manual/en/images/0baa1b9fae6aec55bbb73037f3016001-xkcd-goto.png

Comment: @DipeshParmar there is a famous piece by Edsger Dijkstra elaborating this (from 1968!). From the wikipedia page, I found this quote: "The unbridled use of the go to statement has as an immediate consequence that it becomes terribly hard to find a meaningful set of coordinates in which to describe the process progress. ... The go to statement as it stands is just too primitive, it is too much an invitation to make a mess of one's program.". Google `goto considered harmful` and you'll find more info.

Comment: @Sann while funny, not very useful ;).

Comment: @Voitcus it still yields different result as it doesn't skip `echo "i = $i";`

Comment: @BartFriederichs This one may be more useful - http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php

Comment: @Sann not really as it doesn't tell DipeshParmar that it is bad practice.

Comment: @BartFriederichs thanx for information but i think from OP question this one might help OP..

Comment: Prefer multi-level `break` over `goto`. Essentially, **AVOID** `goto`.

Comment: @DipeshParmar perhaps in a "use-duck-tape-to-fix-a-leak" kind of way. Not in a "let's-build-robust-software" kind of way.

Answer (score 0):

Use multilevel break, like this one -

```
$flag=0;
while(true) {
    while($cond) {
        if($cond2) {
            $flag=1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if($flag) break;
}
```

Comment: Why not use `break 2` ?

Comment: @BartFriederichs Because the first break won't break you out of the first loop.

Comment: that's exactly what `break 2` does.